# In Swift 2: cannot trigger calloutAccessoryControlTapped for clicks on map annotation

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, annotations, mapkit

I am working on a person project that allows users to add annotation pins to the map, followed by downloading photos from Flickr for the chosen location. The pins/annotations are clickable so as to trigger certain functions (e.g. deletion or triggering segue to a detail view). I am currently stumbled upon making the `callout action` work. Below is the code I have written:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    let reusedPinId = "pin"
    var selectedLocation: TouringLocationAnnotation!
    let initLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 21.282788, longitude: -157.829444)
    let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 1000
    var myPin: MKPinAnnotationView?
    var editModeOn = false


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer()
        longPressRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: "addMapAnnotation:")
        mapView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)
        mapView.delegate = self
        centerMapOnLocation(initLocation)

        let touringSpot = TouringSpot(title: "Picture at this touring site", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 21.283921, longitude: -157.831661))
        mapView.addAnnotation(touringSpot) //TODO: change this to the first pin
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem() //toggle edit and Done
        self.navigationItem.title = "Virtual Tourist"

        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

        do {
            try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()

            if let savedPins = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects {
                for pin in savedPins {
                    print("retrieved a pin from coredata")
                    showPinOnMap(pin as! Pin)
                }
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("error in retrieving saved pins: \(error)")
        }

    }

//show the pin as an annotation on map
    func showPinOnMap(pin: Pin) {
        if pin.isValid() { //check if the pin has coordinate set up
            let locationAnnot = TouringLocationAnnotation(tourLocationPin: pin)
            //TODO: fetch photo for the pin
            if pin.photos.count == 0 {
                print("about to fetch flickr photos for pin:")
                pin.fetchPhotosFromFlickr({ (success, error) -> Void in
                    if success {
                        print("successfl in fetching flickr photos")
                    } else {
                        print("error in fetching flickr photos")
                        //TODO: give warning to user
                        return
                    }
                });
            }
            mapView.addAnnotation(locationAnnot)
        } else {
            print("pin is invalid")
            //TODO: give warning to user on invalid pin
        }
    }


    func centerMapOnLocation(location: CLLocation) {
        let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, regionRadius * 2.0, regionRadius * 2.0)
        mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
    }
}
```

**Below is the method for adding map annotations:**

```
func centerMapOnLocation(location: CLLocation) {
        let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, regionRadius * 2.0, regionRadius * 2.0)
        mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
    }


    func addMapAnnotation(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        if gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
            let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(mapView)
            let newCoordinate = mapView.convertPoint(touchPoint, toCoordinateFromView: mapView)
            let annotation = TouringSpot(title: "new spot", coordinate: newCoordinate)
            var locationNameStr = ""
            let locationDictionary: [String:AnyObject] = [
                Pin.Keys.Name: "\(newCoordinate.latitude, newCoordinate.longitude)",
                Pin.Keys.Latitude: newCoordinate.latitude,
                Pin.Keys.Longitude: newCoordinate.longitude
            ]
            defer {
                //TODO: check for duplicate pins in database first?
                let newPin = Pin(dictionary: locationDictionary, context: sharedContext)
                newPin.name = locationNameStr

                do {
                //persist the new pin to core data
                    try sharedContext.save()
                    print("saved a pin!")
                    showPinOnMap(newPin)
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print("error saving the new pin in context")
                }
            }


            //problem: cannot pass the locationNameStr to the defer{} block
            //TODO: retrieve the location name as title of the annotation
            CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(CLLocation(latitude: newCoordinate.latitude, longitude: newCoordinate.longitude), completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in

                if error != nil {
                    print("reverse geocoding failed with error: \(error)")
                    //return
                } else if placemarks!.count > 0 {
                    let firstPlace = placemarks![0] as CLPlacemark

                    if firstPlace.country != nil {
                        locationNameStr = "a place in \(firstPlace.country!)"
                    }
                    else if firstPlace.locality != nil {
                        locationNameStr = "a place in \(firstPlace.locality!)"
                    }
                    print("location name: \(locationNameStr)")
                }
            })

        }
    }
```

**When the Edit button is clicked, the user can click on a pin for deletion:**

```
override func setEditing(editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)

        if editing {
            print("going to edit the pins")

            let titleDict: NSDictionary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()
            ]
            navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = titleDict as! [String : AnyObject]

            self.navigationItem.title = "Click a pin for deletion"
            editModeOn = true
        } else {
            print("done with editing the pins")
            let titleDict: NSDictionary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor()
            ]
            navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = titleDict as! [String : AnyObject]
            self.navigationItem.title = "Tourist"
            editModeOn = false
        }
    }
```

**Below is my implementation of the `MKMapViewDelegate`:**

```
extension ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        if let anno = annotation as? TouringLocationAnnotation {
            print("calling the viewForAnnotation delegate")
            var pinView: MKPinAnnotationView!
            if let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reusedPinId)
                as? MKPinAnnotationView {
                    dequeuedView.annotation = anno
                    pinView = dequeuedView
            } else {
                pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: anno, reuseIdentifier: reusedPinId)

            }
            pinView.canShowCallout = true
            if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
                pinView.pinTintColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
            pinView.animatesDrop = true
            // pinView.calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -5, y: 5)

            let btn = UIButton(type: .DetailDisclosure)
            // btn.addTarget(self, action: Selector("showPhotosForPin:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

            pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn //UIButton.buttonWithType(.DetailDisclosure) as! UIView
            return pinView
        }
        return nil
    }

    //call out
    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView!, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl!) {
        print("callout accessory control triggered!")
        /*
        if let annotation = view.annotation as? TouringLocationAnnotation {
            mapView.removeAnnotation(annotation)
        }
        */
        let annotation = view.annotation as! TouringLocationAnnotation
        if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
            print("right callout button is clicked")
        }
    }


    func showPhotosForPin(sender: UIButton!) {
        print("showing photos for pin")
    }


    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView) {
        let latitude = view.annotation!.coordinate.latitude
        let longitude = view.annotation!.coordinate.longitude
        //let annotation = view.annotation as! TouringLocationAnnotation

        if !editModeOn {
            print("did select the annotation View, getting its coordinates, latitude: \(latitude), longitude: \(longitude)")
            // print("pin is: \(annotation.tourLocationPin.latitude)")
        } else {
            print("for deleting the pin")
        }
    }    
}
```

The pins are persisted in `CoreData`, when the app is started, they are fetched from persistence and annotated on the map. As you can see from the below screenshot, the pins are annotated in purple color (the only red pin is from my hard-coded annotation, which is not from CoreData), I think this suggests that my pins are  converted to `MKAnnotationView` type successfully. However, when I click on the pins, the callout action is not trigger, for which I would expect to see the following printout

```
"callout accessory control triggered!"
```

**Please note that the code for CoreData was ommitted for brevity, as I think they are irrelevant to my question**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is correct. It works fine for me.

[image]

[image]

There is something I am a little curious about.

> However, when I click on the pins, the callout action is not trigger,

When you click pins, `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` is NOT called.

When you click UIButton on pins, `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` is called.

Comment: yes, indeed. I think the main reason for my confusion is that the pin/annotation does not have its title set, so there is not callout showing up.